# How to Chain Proxies With Auth (Proxychain?)

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel, kali-linux

I have my Kali local machine (A). I can SSH into another server (B) and use the proxy settings in Iceweasel or use proxychains to visit 10.2.x.x addresses.

However I can not access a machine (C) on a 10.4.x.x addresses or even ping it from the SSH terminal.

From the SSH terminal, I need to SSH into a 10.3.x.x address first, from there I can ping 10.4.x.x addresses but obviously can't open up iceweasel.

Here is my .conf for proxychains

```
strict_chain

proxy_dns

tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

[ProxyList]
socks5 127.0.0.1 9000
socks5 10.3.3.1 9000 user1 pass1
```

Now when I normally SSH into 10.3.3.1, I don't specify a port, it's just

```
ssh user1@10.3.3.1
```

Am I missing something obvious at all?

**TL;DR:** How do I access a website on a 10.4.x.x address if I have to SSH twice in order to even ping it?